sequelize-typescript addColumn with 'after
I'm creating a column with sequelize with mysql/mariadb. Looking into the DOCs, it is possible to create this column after another column just defining an after attribute in third parameter, but when i'm working with typescript, it is giving me the following type error
Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'after' does not exist in type 'ModelAttributeColumnOptions<Model<any, any>> | AbstractDataTypeConstructor | AbstractDataType'
The migration is the following:
import { QueryInterface } from "sequelize"
import { DataType } from "sequelize-typescript"

module.exports = {
async up(queryInterface: QueryInterface) {
queryInterface.addColumn('Contacts', 'responsible', {
type: DataType.JSON,
after: 'number'
})
},
}

I've tryed to create a type to sequelize, but failed. The type i've tryed is the following, i know that is pretty wrong, i'm new with this "typing"
declare module 'sequelize/types/lib/query-interface' {
    interface QueryInterfaceOptions {
        after?: string
    }
}


For anyone that is searching for the same, i've found the solution


import { DataType, ModelAttributeColumnOptions, QueryInterface, QueryInterfaceOptions, TableName } from 'sequelize'

declare module 'sequelize' {
    interface QueryInterface {
        addColumn(table: TableName, key: string, attribute: AddColumnOptions | DataType, options?: QueryInterfaceOptions): Promise<void>
    }

    interface AddColumnOptions extends ModelAttributeColumnOptions {
        after?: string
    }
}



Or even the better one (that changes ModelAttributeColumnOptions itself)


import { ModelAttributeColumnOptions } from 'sequelize'

declare module 'sequelize' {
    interface ModelAttributeColumnOptions {
        after?: string
    }
}



